# Ubuntu Touch extracting binary blob files

Tags: ubuntu-touch, binary

I'm trying to port Ubuntu Touch for the i9001i (S plus) and I need the binary blob files from the cyanogenmod. Is there a way to get these files without flashing a cyanogenmod rom to my S plus device?

Comment: Pieter, Welcome to askubuntu. Your Question is probably not clear. Do you want to port your mobile or do you want to have it ported and you ask for the images (binary of course) in order to flash the device? If you want to port you will have to dig in quite deeply but can find a lot of resources here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting. If you just want to have it ported check here for your model: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Comment: I want to port it myself, and I'm currently following wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting. I need some of the CM binaries, which can be obtained by flashing my device with CM. I was wondering if I can obtain them without having to flash my device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to port i9001. I have a flashed CyanogenMod on my device, currently EhndroixIII. I tryed to follow the guide but the file tree seems very different, for example, I can't find the 'device' folder. Anyway you can also find the blobs in the zip rom. If you find a CM rom where the file three is correct, or at least you think it should, post that link and I'll try that for you.